# Is there a Flex widget for a common calculator?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I need a calculator for a flex app I am making, and was wondering if there was any official widget prebuilt or already in good quality. I could make one myself but it would be nice to use one that already existed and had a nice api to customize it with. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Seriously, this kind of thing would be so easy to do (and such fun as well) I'm surprised you'd want to buy one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not official or anything, but you should check out this one.
[Yottabyte Calculator](http://yottabyte.net/blog/?p=22)
Source code is [here](http://github.com/jasonfagan/flex_calculator/).

Comment: Thanks, I actually found this eventually myself too and its working fine! Just forgot to answer my own question.